# The smallest number to represent a set of numbers

Tags: algorithms, information-theory

I would like an "algorithm" to find the smallest number that can represent a list of numbers exactly, order included.

As an example, if a list is [2 3 4 6 9], I would like an algorithm to yield a number X such that X contains the information and order of each number in the list so that I can "reverse" X back into the list.

As an example, I have come up with what might be an inefficient algorithm, but one that works nevertheless.

As there are 5 numbers in the list, let us consider five other numbers a,b,c,d and e. We replace 'a' with the first number in the list. We replace 'b' with the sum of the first two numbers. Replace 'c' with the sum of the first three numbers and so on.

In this case, we have a,b,c,d and e equal to 2, 5, 9, 15, and 24. Now I replace each number with a prime number of that index. That is, 2 is replaced by the 2nd prime number. 5 by the 5th prime number and so on. So now we have 5 prime numbers, each larger than the previous one. On multiplying the 5 numbers, we come up with a large number which has these prime numbers as their only prime factors and when considered ascendingly, the order is maintained. So when we just backtrack our steps, we get back the original set of numbers.

This method, although it works, yields quite large products. Is there a better algorithm that I can use that will yield numbers that are a lot smaller than this? If not, and I know this is definitely not the right place to ask, can someone help me come up with one?

I believe it could be useful in information theory.

Comment: you want an hash

Comment: a hash (at least in the computer-science sense) is not reversible right?

Comment: do you have conditions on the list? such as, max length, max number that may appear, etc.?

Comment: I would be very happy if the range of numbers is the set of whole numbers less than 10. As for the list, the length is not predetermined and can vary to any finite extent.

Comment: less than 10? so.. digits? In that case just concatenate them

Comment: Correct. All the values are digits

Comment: Just concatenate them

Comment: That did occur to me. But is that the smallest possible number? Also, when operating with different base representation of numbers (such as hex) or if I decide to change the max number to say, 16, it will not work. This is why I did not explicitly mention "digits" in the question.

Comment: Does your list contain repeated numbers? Are they always monotonically sorted?

Comment: Yes, repeated numbers are possible. No, the list is not monotonically sorted in general.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108253/discussion-between-pradyoth-shandilya-and-exodd).

Comment: There are infinitely many schemes. One could do it lexigraphically: use $0$ as the divider between numbers, but represent it by two $00$ when it occurs as a digit. For example, $707, 20, 1003$ would be represented by $700702000100003$.  To go back, start at the left and move each non-zero digit to the current number. For $0$, check if it is followed by a 2nd $0$. If so remove them both and add a single $0$ to the current number. If not, end the current number and start the next number in the list.

Comment: A more mathematical method would be to convert each number to base $9$. Then string together the digits, using $9$ as the divider between numbers. Interpret the result as a base-$10$ number.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, your first comment is essentially the construct of a delimiter right? That is not what I am looking at. I am looking for techniques that could "minimise" the large numbers I am obtaining. Delimited concatenation certainly does not seem to be the way to go.

Comment: You discuss the concept of concatenation, but neither of you appears to have considered the question of telling where one number ends and the next begins. I know of only two ways to do so: fixed number widths - which limit you to only list numbers within a certain range - or delimiters. As for minimizing output number size, I think you are entirely mistaken. I stongly suspect delimeters are the most efficient of all methods so far discussed. I guarantee either of my delimeter solutions are vastly superior to your primes solution.

Comment: There is an ambiguity in your prime scheme: if a list ends with $0$ entries, it gives the exact same output as for the same list with the ending $0$ entries removed. The first of my schemes has a similar problem, except that it is beginning $0$ entries that mess it up. Ignoring these problems, your scheme outperforms mine only when there are a *lot* of $0$ digits in the list. The base-9 to base-10 scheme does not have the abiguities, but on the other hand doesn't map any list to numbers with $99$ in the digits. Both the prime and $0$-delimeter schemes map lists to every natural number.

Comment: Actually, I don't think the list ending with zero entries results in any issue in my scheme. And again, my scheme in the question is just my way of getting my point across. I don't claim that it is a good one.

Comment: The lists $[1], [1,0], [1, 0, 0 ,0], ...$ are all mapped to the number $2$ under your scheme. My point is that you dismissed my scheme as being really bad, when for most lists, it does significantly better than yours. If we disallow lists with ending $0$s, and reverse my scheme so it has the same weakness of yours, both are bijections. Mine is much superior to everything thus far suggested for most lists. but because of that bijection, the only way it can be better for some lists is to be worse for others. My weakness is lots of $0$ digits. Yours is few zero entries.

Comment: This same comment will apply to any scheme. If it beats a bijective scheme on some lists, it must necessarily be worse on other lists. So the question you need to answer is what sort of lists are most important to be low, and what sort of lists can be allowed to be bad. Without such a guideline, any two bijective schemes do equally well.

Comment: Actually, [1] is mapped to 2, [1,0] is mapped to 4, [1,0,0] is mapped to 8 and so on... Please read the part about taking the sum and converting the list into a monotonic one. And no, I definitely do not dismiss your scheme. I sincerely appreciate it. All I am saying is, I am looking for something better than concatenation. By that, I mean we make use of other properties of numbers instead of treating them simply as characters in an alphabet. I am very sorry if you thought I sounded rude.It simply was not what I was looking for. Plus, I want something significantly better than my scheme.Thanks

Comment: Also, if you want to know the context behind this question, do check https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108253/discussion-between-pradyoth-shandilya-and-exodd out